# cant get values from array using javascript

Tags: javascript

Am trying to get the latitude and the longitude from a callback array. the array sometimes has one object inside and sometimes 2 objects.

> Object { place={...}, reference={...}} OR [Object { place={...},  reference={...}}, Object { place={...},  reference={...}}]

```
    Placemaker.getPlaces(text,function(o){
    console.log(o);
    if (typeof o.match!=='undefined' || o.length==1){
     latitude=o.match.place.centroid.latitude, longitude=o.match.place.centroid.longitude; 
     console.log(latitude,longitude);}
     /*else if(o=='null'){
         latitude='', longitude=''; 
     }*/
     else if (typeof o.match[0]!=='undefined' || o.match.length==2){
        latitude=o.match[0].place.centroid.latitude, longitude=o.match[0].place.centroid.longitude; 
     console.log(latitude,longitude);
     }
```

Basically i can get the latitude and longitude from the array that has one object and not from when there are two set of objects inside .this is the error I get

```
TypeError: o.match is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

else if (typeof o.match[0]!=='undefined' || o.match.length==2){
```

thank you all for your help !

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, shouldn't the `||` being `&&`? Also, it sounds to me like you might want to check if `o.match` is defined first, before checking `o.match[0]`.

Comment: Your `if` condition will return false if `o.match` is `undefined`, so it's a bad idea to have conditions on your `else if` that rely on `o.match` not being `undefined`.

Comment: I tried checking first if o.match is not undefined but am still getting TypeError: o.match.place is undefined ....     CODE     else if (typeof o.match!=='undefined' ){
      if (typeof o.match[0]!=='undefined'){
    latitude=o.match[0].place.centroid.latitude, longitude=o.match[0].place.centroid.longitude; 
    console.log(latitude,longitude);
    }
    }

Comment: @AnthonyGrist how do u suggest i do this?

Comment: @anjelos The error you are not getting is different, since it's complaining about `o.match.place` and not `o.match`. If you set a breakpoint in your browser's developer tools, you can observe what the `o` object you're accepting actually is, and tell what part is `undefined`. Then you just need to make sure you're checking the right parts and handling it appropriately.

Comment: This is not legal javascript `Object { place={...}, reference={...}}` OR `[Object { place={...}, reference={...}}, Object { place={...}, reference={...}}]`.  Show us a real javascript data structure and we can advise on how to access it.  There is no `=` in a javascript data structure definition.

Comment: @jfriend00 http://www.flickr.com/photos/codepo8/3553188917/

Comment: ({match:[{place:{woeId:"23424802", type:"Country", name:"Egypt", centroid:{latitude:"26.8371", longitude:"30.7964"}}, reference:{woeIds:"23424802", placeReferenceId:"1", placeIds:"2", start:"11", end:"16", isPlaintextMarker:"1", text:"Egypt", type:"plaintext", xpath:null}}, {place:{woeId:"2345248", type:"State", name:"North Sinai, EG", centroid:{latitude:"30.4642", longitude:"33.728"}}, reference:{woeIds:"2345248", placeReferenceId:"2", placeIds:"1", start:"60", end:"70", isPlaintextMarker:"1", text:"\u0634\u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0633\u064A\u0646\u0627\u0621", type:"plaintext", xpath:null}}]})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you show in your screenshot is this javascript data structure:

```
var match = [
    {
        place: {
            centroid: {latitude: xx, longitude: yy},
            name: "London, England",
            type: "Town",
            woeld: "44418"
        }
        reference: {...}
    },
    {
        place: {
            centroid: {latitude: xx, longitude: yy},
            name: "Germany",
            type: "Country",
            woeld: "23424829"
        }
        reference: {...}
    }
];
```

You would access the latitude and longitude for each element in the array like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
    var centroid = match[i].place.centroid;
    // latitude is centroid.latitude
    // longitude is centroid.longitude
}
```